# Connect to virtual machine through bridged port

Tags: networking, vmware-workstation

In my setup, I have a virtual machine in VMWare for development purposes using a bridged adapter. I can connect to it from another computer, but not from the host machine. My host is located at `192.168.1.16` and the guest is `192.168.1.10`. Both can connect to the internet, but not to eachother. Upon pinging one IP from the other, I get a `Request timed out` from my host (Windows 10) and `Destination Host Unreachable` from the guest (Ubuntu Server 16.04.1). Is this a limitation of the bridged connector? Or is there some config that I have missed in making this happen?

EDIT: I am connected to my router using an ethernet cable, and the network is listed as a 'private' one

Answer (score 0):

Can you connect to your host computer from the other (Non-VM) computer?
This sounds to me like your host computer is blocking incoming and outgoing pings which is probably a firewall issue. Try ensuring that you're on a "private" network instead of a "public" network.

The best way to check is by going to the Network and Sharing Center and looking for your bridged adapter. If it says Private network (or Domain network) That's not your problem. If it says Public network, you'll have to change it.

The easiest way to change it is to make sure that's the only network you're connected to and go to "Network" (Just type it in the address bar of any explorer window) A yellow bar will drop down telling you that you're not allowing file sharing on public networks. Click on it and you can get a box that lets you either share files on public networks (NO!!!) or change the network you're connected to, to a private network. (Yes!)

Hope that fixes your problem!

Comment: Also, for the record, this is probably better asked on Network Engineering

Comment: Sorry, probably should've stated that it is a private network and I am connected with an ethernet cable. My VMnext1 adapter (the bridged adapter) states that my IP is 192.168.157.1. Is this a problem?

Comment: And yes, I can connect to it from another computer (not the host or guest)

Comment: Are you bridging through VMware? Or through Network Connections?

Comment: I'm bridging through VMware

Comment: Okay, with having done nothing, I can connect via ssh and sftp, but it errors out after a while. Do i need to ask a new question for that?

Comment: @AndrewHendrix, actually, host, server, and VM configurations are off-topic for [networkengineering.se]. If this is for a business network, it may be on-topic for [sf], otherwise it may be on-topic for [su].

Comment: @RonMaupin I was thinking Network Engineering, because it seems like the underlying problem is something Network related, but since that was speculation on my part... Caleb, I'd try asking your revised question on either Super User or Server Fault, depending on if this is a home or business question respectively like Ron mentioned. I'd also try adding another VM and testing interactions with it to try and isolate the cause, and add the results to your new question, and link to your new question in the comments section under your original question.